# How does localization in Django effect server side performance?

Tags: django, performance, web, localization

I used a lot of `{% trans "" %}` tags in my Django templates. 
I am wondering how does Django perform the string replacement on server-side in real-time from the mo file. Does it have a big impact on performance compared with templates without localized strings?

And if it does effect performance, can I compile the templates beforehand (generating templates with the translated strings filled in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything about this [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/).

If you are concerned about the speed impact of translations on your site, it's best to measure it.

1. Disable translations by setting `USE_I18N = False` in your `settings.py`
2. Stress test your site, for example with `ab` (the Apache benchmarking tool), or other
3. Turn translations back on and repeat the stress test

That said, I don't for sure know how Django handles the `{% trans "" %}` tags when `USE_I18N = False`. To be extra paranoid, maybe you can delete all these tags and measure again. I think the results of your benchmark tests would be interesting for everyone.

Comment: Actually I was hoping maybe someone else had done the benchmarking and comparison... But you are right, I need to include this in my stress test. And, is there any third party tools to preprocess the templates to generated tranlated versions, aka, some command line tool that converts template.html to template_jp.html?

Comment: @NeoWang I don't know such tools, but maybe. But I think it's better a  to perform the above tests. In particular, it's relatively easy to remove all occurrences of `{% trans ... %}` from all template files and measure if it makes a difference. Based on that measurement you can decide if it's worth the effort to create the preprocessed versions or not.